# Is there a way for double/parallel authentication in one application?

Tags: java, spring, ssl, spring-security, jwt

I'm building application based on micro services. REST API. For authenticating users I'm using JWT. All that works fine.
But for communication between modules I would like to use ssl client certificates.
I don't know how to deal that when request comes from the outside use JWT, and when request comes from the inside use ssl authentication.
Is there any neat solution for that?

Comment: Spring Security do supports multiple authentication provider. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-multiple-auth-providers

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam I can't make it work. Any request with basic auth and without JWT token fails.